How to add a button or format style in Craft 5 CKEditor 5 (rich text field)
I read this: https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor?tab=readme-ov-file#registering-custom-styles
but to me that is not clear where I should add this code.
Do I have to add this within the CK editor config page in craft?

In my example I tried to change the font family for the editor, but nothing happens.
What I finally want to achieve is a custom format like seen here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/style.html#demo
but showing a button.
Currently I have no idea how that is being done.
I knew my way around in redactor, but now ck editor seems to rule again...
I think I need to add the styles plugin as said on github but there is no explanation how I would install this within craft.

First this video is very handy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etFletL0dYg&ab_channel=CraftQuest
Secondly: I have this code now and I had to make sure that Styles appear within my menu bar of the editor.



What I don't know though is, how I could install a plugin for ckeditor, like the Styles plugin: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/style.html#demo
